How to change the name of vzdump files in proxmox
I have a proxmox server with an attached PBS attached as datastore, when I try to create a backup I've got this error:
INFO: creating Proxmox Backup Server archive 'vm/200/2024-08-13T00:50:36Z'
INFO: issuing guest-agent 'fs-freeze' command
INFO: issuing guest-agent 'fs-thaw' command
ERROR: VM 200 qmp command 'backup' failed - backup connect failed: command error: Invalid argument (os error 22)
INFO: aborting backup job
INFO: resuming VM again
ERROR: VM 200 qmp command 'backup' failed - backup connect failed: command error: Invalid argument (os error 22)

it turns out that the filename includes the timestamp of operation and it contains colon character that are not accepted by the filesystem (exfat), is there any way to change the format of vzdump files??

Don't use exfat on PBS. Period. Nothing to talk about. Use the decent supported filesystem, like zfs or ext4 or xfs.
